# Create Search Function including AND OR vb .net

Tags: sql, vb.net, function, search, datagridview

Hope you can help me out and inspire me here

I am looking to create a Search function that searches through a datagridview column looking for key words and then filtering based on the result. I have done this already and it works fine. However this is based on the user entering strings into the textbox separating their strings with a comma. So an example would be
A DataGridViewColumn with 3 values

```
ERROR_QUEUE_MAY05
ERROR_QUEUE_MAY06
ORDER_QUEUE_JAN01
```

The User then enters the search criteria

ORDER, 06

And the result would be

ERROR_QUEUE_MAY06
ORDER_QUEUE_JAN01

As you can see the filter has used an OR to filter the column

I want the user to be able to use brackets () and also AND statements like you would in a SQL statement so they could use for example

("ORDER" AND "MAY") OR "03"

This would filter the results to show anything with ORDER and MAY in the title or 03.

Has anyone done anything like this in the past or have any ideas of going about it?

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to scan the string from left to right, then recursively call the evaluator every time parentheses are encountered. After a recursive call, replace the parenthesized expression with "true" or "false". If you intend to allow `and` a higher priority than `or`, you can treat that recursively as well.